# Cauchy Condensation Test - Proof

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, cauchy-sequences

I have the following proof for the Cauchy condensation test in my lecture notes. I can understand all that has been carried out except for the conclusion. Can you help explain why the sequences are either both bounded or both unbounded?

[image: Cauchy Condensation test proof]

By theorem 3.8, it's referring to the following:

> A series of non-negative terms converges *iff* the sequence of partial sums is bounded above.

Comment: @Masacroso That's what the proof is doing though, isn't it? Since it's a $\iff$, they must either both converge or both diverge.

Comment: yes : $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=n_k}^{n_{k+1}-1} a_n$ and since  $(a_n)$ is decreasing : $  (n_{k+1}-n_k) a_{k+1} \le\sum_{n=n_k}^{n_{k+1}-1} a_n \le (n_{k+1}-n_k) a_{k} $ . the Cauchy condensation test is with $n_k = 2^{k-1}$

Comment: You can read that there is a lineal relation between the maximal condensed series and the minimal condensed series. So if one diverges the other diverges too, and cause the original series is in between it converges or diverges depending of the other. In other words $\infty=\frac12\cdot\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally find the wording of the last paragraph confusing, so maybe it'd help to see it that way:

- Assume $(T_k)_k$ is convergent, and let $T\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\lim_{k\to\infty} T_k\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, for any fixed $n$, taking the limit as $k\to \infty$ in the first inequality (which holds, since $k\to\infty$ we have $n \leq 2^k-1$ for $k$ large enough)
  $$
  S_n \leq \lim_{k\to\infty} T_k = T
  $$
  and $(S_n)_n$ is a bounded series of non-negative terms: it converges by Theorem 3.8.
- Assume $(S_n)_n$ is convergent, and let $S\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n \in\mathbb{R}$. Then, for any fixed $k$, taking the limit as $n\to \infty$ in the second inequality (which holds, since $n\to\infty$ we have $n \geq 2^{k-1}$ for $n$ large enough)
  $$
  T_k \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} 2S_n = 2S
  $$
  and $(T_k)_k$ is a bounded series of non-negative terms: it converges by Theorem 3.8.

This shows the equivalence.

Comment: Thanks! That should be $\displaystyle\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}2\boldsymbol{S}_n$ though right?

Comment: Yes, I'm going to edit to remove the typo. Thanks.