# Convergence of $\sum_{n\ge16}^{ }\frac{1}{n\ln n\left(\ln\ln n\right)^{p}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to show that $$\sum_{n\ge16}^{ }\frac{1}{n\ln n\left(\ln\ln n\right)^{p}}$$

Converges for $p>1$ **Just** by using Cauchy condensation test?

---

I applied the test , but I cannot continue:

$$\sum_{n\ge15}^{ }\frac{1}{n\ln2\left(\ln\left(n\ln2\right)\right)^{p}}$$

again:

$$\sum_{n\ge14}^{ }\frac{1}{\ln2\left(\ln\left(2^{n}\ln2\right)\right)^{p}}=\sum_{n\ge14}^{ }\frac{1}{\ln2\left(\ln\left(2^{n}\right)+\ln\ln\left(2\right)\right)^{p}}$$

again:

$$\sum_{n\ge13}^{ }\frac{1}{\ln2\left(2^{n}\ln\left(2\right)+\ln\ln\left(2\right)\right)^{p}}$$

So what now?

Comment: Cauchy test is a requirement? Too bad, integral test would be very easy to apply here.

Comment: @ user170231,yes that's true, but this is just because of my interest in this tests and I want to know the applications

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/280257/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper statement is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1819789/779382). Have a look before we proceed.
$$ \frac{2^n}{2^n\ln 2^n\left(\ln\ln (2^n)\right)^{p}}=\frac{1}{(n\ln 2)\left(\ln (n \ln 2)\right)^{p}}$$
Observe,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\frac{1}{n\left(\ln n\right)^{p}}}{\frac{1}{(n\ln 2)\left(\ln (n \ln 2)\right)^{p}}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{(n\ln 2)\left(\ln (n \ln 2)\right)^{p}}{n\left(\ln n\right)^{p}}=\ln 2$$

So series
$$\sum_{n\ge1}^{ }\frac{1}{(n\ln 2)\left(\ln (n \ln 2)\right)^{p}}$$ and $$ \sum_{n\ge1}^{ }\frac{1}{n\left(\ln n\right)^{p}} $$converges or diverges simultaneously. 
Now we look at a new series $$\sum_{n\ge1}^{ }\frac{1}{n\left(\ln n\right)^{p}}$$
Again we look at (**Cauchy-condensation test**)
$$\frac{2^n}{2^n\left(\ln (2^n)\right)^{p}}=\frac{1}{\left( n \ln (2)\right)^{p}}=\frac{1}{n^p\left(\ln (2)\right)^{p}}$$
Now we get the series $$\sum_{n\ge1}^{ }\frac{1}{n^p\left(\ln (2)\right)^{p}}$$
this last series converges when $p>1$. And hence by cauchy-condensation test the above series converges for  $p>1$.
You apply Cauchy-Condensation Test **twice**.

Comment: how the lat series help us with the main series?

Comment: @user715522 by Cauchy-condensation test we can say all the series mentioned here can converge or diverge simultaneously..

Comment: @user715522 thank you for your question by the way

Comment: Well thank you for your answer,just a question, why did you use limits?is it followed by a test or theorem?

Comment: I used the theorem to show the simultaneous convergence. And if you ask me the proof of the fact that it converges simultaneously..then i would say its a easy consequence of $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit and comparison test. @user715522 thanks again

Comment: I think the limit is wrong since:$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n\ln\left(2\right)\left(\ln\left(n\ln\left(2\right)\right)\right)^{p}}{n\left(\ln\left(n\right)\right)^{p}}$$$$=\ln\left(2\right)\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln\left(n\ln\left(2\right)\right)}{\ln\left(n\right)}\right)^{p}$$$$=\ln\left(2\right)\left(1\right)^{p}=\ln\left(2\right)$$

Comment: @user715522 yes you are right thank you for the correction.

Comment: @ Noob mathematician,you're welcome, now I think their behavior is not he same.

Comment: Still they are same . It is the same if you get a nonzero positive limit . That is what you say by comparison test

Comment: I think you are using limit comparison test, right?

Comment: Yes! Basically all the other tests for convergence are derived from comparision test .

Answer (score 1):

Applying the test once gives that the original series converges iff
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 15}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n\log 2(\log n + \log\log 2)^p }}}
$$
converges. But
$$
\frac{2^p}{{\log 2}}\sum\limits_{n = 15}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n\log ^p n}}} \geq \sum\limits_{n = 15}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n\log 2(\log n + \log\log 2)^p }}}  \ge \frac{1}{{\log 2}}\sum\limits_{n = 15}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n\log ^p n}}} .
$$
The series $\sum\nolimits_{n = 15}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n\log ^p n}}}$ converges iff
$$
\frac{1}{{\log ^p 2}}\sum\limits_{n = 15}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^p }}} 
$$
converges, which happens precisely when $p>1$.

Comment: how did you get that lower and upper bounds?

Comment: I just think it should be $$\sum_{n\ge15}^{ }\frac{1}{n\ln2\left(\ln\left(n\ln2\right)\right)^{p}}$$ instead of $$
\sum\limits_{n = 15}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n\log 2(\log n + \log 2)^p }}}
$$ they are not the same thing

Comment: Corrected. Use $\log n > \log n +\log \log 2>(\log n)/2$ which definitely holds for $n\geq 15$.